# Calling the constructor of a subclass from a baseclass

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

Say you have an abstract base class:

```
abstract class abstractBaseClass {
    public abstractBaseClass(object argument);

    public abstractBaseClass instanceMethod() {
         //call the constructor of the concrete class here.
    }
}
```

And you have a base class:

```
class baseClass {
    public baseClass(object argument) : abstractBaseClass(object argument)
}
```

If you have an instance method on `abstractBaseClass` is there any way to call the constructor of that concrete class inside the instance method without resorting to reflection?

It seems to be reasonable to assume there is at least one constructor with the signature `concreteBaseClass(object)` on any given concrete base class.

Comment: Are you saying you want to call `baseClass`'s constructor from an instance method on `abstractBaseClass`?

Comment: Without Constructor call, how can you have your instance for abstractBaseClass?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your sample code: In an abstract class (`abstractBaseClass`), the constructor is not marked as `abstract` itself.

Comment: It would be simple enough to do if it were a parameterless constructor through generic constraints, but I think you'll need to use reflection if you want to have a constructor with parameters.

Comment: *It seems to be reasonable to assume there is at least one constructor with the signature `concreteBaseClass(object)` on any given concrete base class.* -- that's not true.  `concrete() : base("someValue")` would compile just fine.

Comment: That's a pretty crucial insight.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't pursue this.  An instance method can't call a constructor because you don't have an instance yet, so even if you found a way to hack around this with reflection, chances are your objects would not be initialized correctly.  As someone else has stated, it sounds like you need to use a factory or maybe use another pattern.  If you provide details on WHY instead of HOW, you may get more appropriate suggestions.

Comment: Assuming you do something like `abstractBaseClass a = new baseClass(argument)`, the constructor on `baseClass` will already have run before your code has a chance to call `a.instanceMethod()`. Why do you want to run it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you have an instance method on abstractBaseClass is there any way
>   to call the constructor of that concrete class

You already do that, actually. `Abstract` class can not be initialized if not by it's derivates.

```
abstractBaseClass  abs  = new baseClass();
```

The **real** object type here is `baseClass`, so the `ctor` of it will be called by convention.

**EDIT**

**if** you mean construct *a new * real object that is hosted inside abstract reference (something that is mantioned by Sevy in comments), I would suggest, at this point, just use 
override pattern. Something like this:

```
abstract class abstractBaseClass {
    public abstract abstractBaseClass(object argument);
    public abstract abstractBaseClass CreateMe();
}


class baseClass : abstractBaseClass
{
   ...
   public override abstractBaseClass CreateMe(){
      return new baseClass();
   }
}
```

after use it like

```
abstractBaseClass  newAbs = abs.CreateMe();
```

Something like this, just an idea.
You should figure out by yourself the real, concrete implementation that fits your needs.

Comment: I assume he means create a new instance; that's the only way it makes sense.  For example, assume the class were immutable and the methods all need to return new instances.

Comment: @Servy: do you mean, some kind of "factory" ?

Comment: That's one possibility, yes.  I'm not the OP, I'm just theorizing.

Comment: I've updated the original question to more clearly communicate that this is about calling the constructor from within an instance method on the abstract class.

Comment: This really sounds like C# doesn't support such a simple abstraction out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, "can I just call `new baseClass()` inside of `abstractBaseClass`, then yes, you can.

If you mean "can I dynamically figure out what class inherits from me and new one up", then no, not without using reflection. You have no way of knowing if there are more than one types inheriting from you.

This is, by the way, a pretty weird scenario and sounds like it violates a whole lot of best practices for OOP. Perhaps you would be better off creating a factory class to create your objects?

Comment: Beware of infinite loops with your first statement.

Comment: The thought is, if you have an instance of a class it was created with some constructor.  It has some concrete type.  Is the C# compiler smart enough to give access to that?

Comment: It sounds like the answer below from @Tigran is what you want, then - a `CreateMe()` method would create another of that concrete type, thanks to polymorphism.